# Extracting output from linear regression in r

Tags: r

I want to extract a selected output from the lm function. This is the code i have,

```
fastfood <- openintro::fastfood

L1 = lm(formula = calories~sat_fat +fiber+sugar, fastfood)
summary(L1)
```

This is the output

```
Call:
lm(formula = calories ~ sat_fat + fiber + sugar, data = fastfood)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-680.18  -88.97  -24.65   57.46 1501.07 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  113.334     15.760   7.191 2.36e-12 ***
sat_fat       30.839      1.180  26.132  < 2e-16 ***
fiber         24.396      2.444   9.983  < 2e-16 ***
sugar          8.890      1.120   7.938 1.37e-14 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 160.8 on 499 degrees of freedom
  (12 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.6726,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6707 
F-statistic: 341.7 on 3 and 499 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

I need to extract only the follwing from above output ? How do i get to this?

```
sat_fat       30.839.
```

Answer (score 4):

Most commonly `coef()` is used to return the coefficients *e.g.*

```
coef(L1)
coef(L1)['sat_fat']
```

You may also want to look at `tidy` in the `broom` package which returns a nice summary as a dataframe, with coefficients in the `estimate` column.